# How removing an outcome affects remaining probabilities

Tags: probability

I got this idea from a videogame on my phone. There's an item that can give you random effects where there is a 50% chance of getting nothing, a certain chance of a good prize and another chance for a greater prize. But if your character is playing with a luck bonus, it guarantees that the outcome where you get nothing won't happen. In my head, the way you would code that is rolling the item like usual, but if you get the nothing outcome, just try again until you get one of the prizes. So, if the two different prizes start with probabilities (like 30% and 20%) what would the new probabilities be?

I can call the original probabilities $p$ and $q$, and the new ones will be $P$ and $Q$. Originally the chance of getting nothing is 50% so $p+q=1/2$. Afterwards the chance of getting nothing is zero, so $P+Q=1$. My idea for finding $P$ and $Q$ in terms of $p$ and $q$ is that if you assume the ratio of the probabilities doesn't change, then $\,p/q=P/Q$. Now we have two equations involving $P$ and $Q$ and we solve.

My question is if the ratio assumption is justified. If the assumption is incorrect, what is the right way to find the new probabilities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. Let $X$ and $Y$ be the two events with original probabilities $p$ and $q$ respectively.
With this "luck bonus", the new $P$ should be
$P = \Pr[X \mid X \lor Y] = \Pr[X] / (\Pr[X] + \Pr[Y]) = p / (p + q)$;
similarly,
$Q = \Pr[Y \mid X \lor Y] = \Pr[Y] / (\Pr[X] + \Pr[Y]) = q / (p + q)$.

But regarding coding, I think you can just modify the probabilities instead of rolling it multiple times.